# SourceTree doesn't auto refresh after version update

Tags: windows, git, versioning, atlassian-sourcetree

After updating to Sourcetree 3.3.6, there is no automatic page update. I checked the settings:

[image: img]

The only way to refresh a page is to do it manually (F5).

How can I fix it to make the auto-refresh work again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove your "old" bookmarks:

[image: img2]

and create them again:

[image: img3]

Comment: Cheers. This has been annoying me for days!